# pthread_kill() gives segmentation fault when called from second thread

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to manually interrupt the main thread of a program when it is blocked on a `read()` system call. I do this in a second thread with a call to `pthread_kill()` however a segmentation fault occurs. However if I place the call to `read()` in the scond thread, i.e. NOT the main thread and call `pthread_kill()` from the main thread then all works as expected.

For example, the following code results in a segmentation fault, where I call `pthread_kill()` in the second thread, approximatelt 2 seconds after it is started. It uses the `pthread_t` of the main thread obtained by a call (in the main thread) to `pthread_self()`:

**Example 1**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>


static int fd = 0;
unsigned char buf[255];
static pthread_t s;
void sigHandler(int sig){
    printf("Signal handler called.\n");
}

void * closeFD(void *arg){
    printf("Second thread started.\n");
    sleep(2);
    int r = pthread_kill(s, SIGUSR1);
}

int main(char *argv[], int argc){
    struct termios newtio;
    pthread_t t1;
    unsigned char buf[255];
    void *res;
    struct sigaction int_handler = {.sa_handler=sigHandler};
    sigaction(SIGUSR1,&int_handler,0);
    s = pthread_self();
    printf("Process id is: %d.\n", getpid());
    fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY);
    if (fd != -1){
        bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio));
        newtio.c_cflag = B2400 | CS7 | CLOCAL | CREAD ;
        newtio.c_iflag = ICRNL;
        newtio.c_oflag = 0;
        newtio.c_lflag = ~ICANON;
        newtio.c_cc[VMIN]     = 14;
        tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);
        pthread_create(&t1, NULL, closeFD, NULL);
        printf("Reading ..\n");
        read(fd,buf,255);
        close(fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The following code is the same except I place the call to `read()` in the second thread (in `closeFD()`) and works as expected. The second thread unblocks and terminates while the main thread waits for it to exit then exits itself.

**Example 2:**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>


static int fd = 0;
unsigned char buf[255];
static pthread_t s;
void sigHandler(int sig){
    printf("Signal handler called.\n");
}

void * closeFD(void *arg){
    printf("Second thread started.\n");
    read(fd,buf,255);
    printf("Read interrupted.\n");
}

int main(char *argv[], int argc){
    struct termios newtio;
    pthread_t t1;
    unsigned char buf[255];
    void *res;
        struct sigaction int_handler = {.sa_handler=sigHandler};
        sigaction(SIGUSR1,&int_handler,0);
        s = pthread_self();
        printf("Process id is: %d.\n", getpid());
        fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY);
        if (fd != -1){
            bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio));
            newtio.c_cflag = B2400 | CS7 | CLOCAL | CREAD ;
            newtio.c_iflag = ICRNL;
            newtio.c_oflag = 0;
            newtio.c_lflag = ~ICANON;
            newtio.c_cc[VMIN]     = 14;
            tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);
            pthread_create(&t1, NULL, closeFD, NULL);
            sleep(2);
            int r = pthread_kill(t1, SIGUSR1);
            pthread_join(t1, &res);
            close(fd);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

So far I have not been able to find a specific reference stating that terminating the main thread from a second (within the same process) is an illegal operation, so is there something I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE #1**
Thanks for all those that have replied, however I should make a few points clear:

1. I am aware that using `printf` in the signal handler is unsafe however this is an example and it's not the cause of the segmentation fault, though it is a valid point. Taking the `printf()` out of the signal handler still results in a segmentation fault. Example 2 works with `printf()` either in or out of the signal handler.
2. I know sending a SIGUSR will not terminate the program. However by using the `pthread_kill(pthread_t thread, int signal)` it WILL send a signal to the thread `thread` and it will unblock (if indeed it is blocked). This is the action I desire, this is what actually happens in Example 2 and this is what I understand *should* happen in either example, but does not in example 1.
3. When describing example 1, I used the term 'method' when I meant 'thread', where I mention the call to `pthread_kill()`.

Further, quoting from 'Programming with POSIX Threads', David R. Butenhof, section 6.6.3 p217 'pthread_kill':

> Within a process, one thread can send a signal to a **specific thread
>   (including itself)** by calling `pthread_kill`.

With that said, the following example ALSO gives a segmentation fault:

**Example 3**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>



static pthread_t s;
int value = 0;

void sigHandler(int sig){
    value = 1;
}


int main(char *argv[], int argc){

    struct sigaction int_handler = {.sa_handler=sigHandler};
    sigaction(SIGUSR1,&int_handler,0);
    s = pthread_self();
    printf("The value of 'value' is %d.\n", value);
    printf("Process id is: %d.\n", getpid());
    int r = pthread_kill(s, SIGUSR1);
    printf("The value of 'value' is %d.\n", value);
    return 0;
}
```

This also fails if instead of a call to `sigaction()` is replaced by the (non-portable) call to `signal()`. With the third example in mind, which is *very* simple, I am not able to find any documentation that expressly states it is an illegal action. In fact the quoted reference indicates it's allowable!

Comment: AFAIK `printf` is not async signal safe, so both of your programs have undefined behavior. (Not saying that this will change the behavior that you observe.)

Comment: I tried to reproduce this problem, but I don't have access to /dev/ttyS0 on the system I'm using.  So I tried having the main thread do `sleep(10)` instead of reading from a file and it ran the signal handler correctly without a segfault.  Do you still get a segfault if you don't have the main thread read from /dev/ttyS0?

Comment: this line, in the thread: 'int r = pthread_kill(s, SIGUSR1);' will kill the current thread, not the main thread.  suggest using something like 'pthread_exit(null)' to exit the current thread.  main() could be doing something like pthread_join(s); to wait for the thread to complete

Comment: Hi all, please see my original post where I have added further information and another failing example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to `#include <pthread.h>`.  That fixes your segfault for me in example #3 on a recent Linux system.

```
--- pthread_kill-self.c.orig    2015-01-06 14:08:54.949000690 -0600
+++ pthread_kill-self.c 2015-01-06 14:08:59.820998965 -0600
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
-#include <string.h>
+#include <pthread.h>
 #include <signal.h>
```

and then...

```
$:- gcc -o pthread_kill-self pthread_kill-self.c -pthread
$:- ./pthread_kill-self 
The value of 'value' is 0.
Process id is: 3152.
The value of 'value' is 1.
```

Comment: By the way `-Wall` complains about this for me.

Comment: Oh man, I am red-faced! I knew it *had* to be something simple like that! I wasn't using the -Wall commandline switch. It has made me realise I need to read up *much* more about pthreads. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're using `printf()`, which is not [async-signal safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), and you're not initializing your [struct sigaction](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) properly (in particular, the signal mask is left undefined).

Third, sending a `SIGUSR1` signal, with a handler installed, does not and should not *terminate* the main thread. You're just sending it a signal, that's all.

As Jens Gustedt mentioned in his comment to the original question, both of the programs have undefined behaviour. Therefore, I'm not going to try and guess exactly what part of the undefined behaviour causes the segmentation fault (in the first program).

Instead, I'll show you a working example.

For debugging/testing purposes, I like to start with async-signal safe output functions, based on [`write(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html):

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

#define  MYSIGNAL  SIGUSR1

#define  SECONDS   10

static int wrstr(const int descriptor, const char *p, const char *const q)
{
    while (p < q) {
        ssize_t n;

        n = write(descriptor, p, (size_t)(q - p));
        if (n > (ssize_t)0)
            p += n;
        else
        if (n != (ssize_t)-1)
            return EIO;
        else
        if (errno != EINTR && errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
            return errno;
    }

    return 0;
}

static const char *ends(const char *s)
{
    if (s)
        while (*s != '\0')
            s++;
    return s;
}

static int wrout(const char *const p)
{
    if (p != NULL && *p != '\0') {
        int saved_errno, result;
        saved_errno = errno;
        result = wrstr(STDOUT_FILENO, p, ends(p));
        errno = saved_errno;
        return result;
    } else
        return 0;
}

static int wrouti(const int value)
{
    char          buffer[32];
    char         *p = buffer + sizeof buffer;
    unsigned int  u;

    if (value < 0)
        u = -(long)value;
    else
        u = value;

    do {
        *(--p) = '0' + (u % 10U);
        u /= 10U;
    } while (u > 0U);

    if (value < 0)
        *(--p) = '-';

    return wrstr(STDOUT_FILENO, p, buffer + sizeof buffer);
}

static int wrerr(const char *const p)
{
    if (p != NULL && *p != '\0') {
        int saved_errno, result;
        saved_errno = errno;
        result = wrstr(STDERR_FILENO, p, ends(p));
        errno = saved_errno;
        return result;
    } else
        return 0;
}
```

The above functions are async-signal safe, and therefore okay to use in a signal handler. `wrout()` and `wrerr()` also retain `errno` unchanged, which is useful. Saving and restoring `errno` in a signal handler is usually omitted, by the way, although I do believe there are some odd corner cases it might matter. The `wrouti()` is just a crude decimal signed integer printer, also async-signal-safe, but it does not retain `errno` unchanged.

Next, let's define the signal handler itself, and an installer function for it. (I like to do it this way, to make the `main()` simpler.)

```
static volatile sig_atomic_t handled = 0;

static void handler(int signum)
{
    wrerr("Signal received.\n");
    handled = signum;
}

static int install_handler(const int signum)
{
    struct sigaction act;

    /* memset(&act, 0, sizeof act); */   
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = handler;
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    if (sigaction(signum, &act, NULL))
        return errno;

    return 0;
}
```

The commented-out memset is recommended, but not required for proper operation. The [`sigemptyset()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigsetops.3.html), however, is required, to clear the set of blocked signals.

Next, let's look at the thread function. You shouldn't use sleep(), as that interacts with signals; use POSIX.1-2001 [`nanosleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) instead.

```
static void *worker(void *target)
{
    struct timespec duration, left;
    int retval;

    wrout("Worker started. Sleeping ");
    wrouti((int)SECONDS);
    wrout(" seconds...\n");

    duration.tv_sec = SECONDS;
    duration.tv_nsec = 0;
    left.tv_sec = 0;
    left.tv_nsec = 0;

    while (1) {
        retval = nanosleep(&duration, &left);
        if (retval == 0)
            break;

        if (left.tv_sec <= 0 ||
            (left.tv_sec == 0 && left.tv_nsec <= 0))
            break;

        duration = left;
        left.tv_sec = 0;
        left.tv_nsec = 0;
    }

    wrout("Sleep complete.\n");

    if (target) {
        wrout("Sending signal...\n");

        retval = pthread_kill(*(pthread_t *)target, MYSIGNAL);
        if (retval == 0)
            wrout("Signal sent successfully.\n");
        else {
            const char *const errmsg = strerror(retval);
            wrout("Failed to send signal: ");
            wrout(errmsg);
            wrout(".\n");
        }
    }

    wrout("Thread done.\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

The pointer given to the thread function should point to the thread identifier (`pthread_t`) the signal is directed to.

Note that above, `nanosleep()` can be interrupted by a signal delivery, if the signal is delivered to or caught by this particular thread. If that occurs, `nanosleep()` tells us how much time was left to sleep. The loop above shows how to make sure you sleep at least the specified time, even if interrupted by signal delivery.

Finally, the `main()`. Instead of opening a specific device, I use standard input. To reproduce OP's program, redirect standard input from `/dev/ttyUSB0`, i.e. `./program < /dev/ttyUSB0`, when executing it.

```
int main(void)
{
    pthread_t main_thread, worker_thread;
    pthread_attr_t attrs;
    struct termios original, settings;
    int result;

    if (!isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
        wrerr("Standard input is not a terminal.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &original) != 0 ||
        tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &settings) != 0) {
        const char *const errmsg = strerror(errno);
        wrerr("Cannot get terminal settings: ");
        wrerr(errmsg);
        wrerr(".\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    settings.c_lflag = ~ICANON;
    settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 14;

    if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &settings) != 0) {
        const char *const errmsg = strerror(errno);
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &original);
        wrerr("Cannot set terminal settings: ");
        wrerr(errmsg);
        wrerr(".\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    wrout("Terminal is now in raw mode.\n");

    if (install_handler(MYSIGNAL)) {
        const char *const errmsg = strerror(errno);
        wrerr("Cannot install signal handler: ");
        wrerr(errmsg);
        wrerr(".\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    main_thread = pthread_self();

    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, 65536);

    result = pthread_create(&worker_thread, &attrs, worker, &main_thread);
    if (result != 0) {
        const char *const errmsg = strerror(errno);
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &original);
        wrerr("Cannot create a worker thread: ");
        wrerr(errmsg);
        wrerr(".\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);

    wrout("Waiting for input...\n");

    while (1) {
        char    buffer[256];
        ssize_t n;

        if (handled) {
            wrout("Because signal was received, no more input is read.\n");
            break;
        }

        n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, sizeof buffer);
        if (n > (ssize_t)0) {
            wrout("Read ");
            wrouti((int)n);
            wrout(" bytes.\n");
            continue;

        } else
        if (n == (ssize_t)0) {
            wrout("End of input.\n");
            break;

        } else
        if (n != (ssize_t)-1) {
            wrout("read() returned an invalid value.\n");
            break;

        } else {
            result = errno;

            wrout("read() == -1, errno == ");
            wrouti(result);
            wrout(": ");
            wrout(strerror(result));
            wrout(".\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    wrout("Reaping the worker thread..\n");
    result = pthread_join(worker_thread, NULL);
    if (result != 0) {
        wrout("Failed to reap worker thread: ");
        wrout(strerror(result));
        wrout(".\n");
    } else
        wrout("Worker thread reaped successfully.\n");

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &original);
    wrout("Terminal reverted back to original mode.\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Because it's much more fun to test using the terminal, the above tries hard to restore the terminal to its original state before returning.

Note that since the `VMIN` field in the termios structure is set to `14`, the `read()` blocks until at least 14 bytes are available in the buffer. If a signal is delivered, a *short count* is returned if there is at least one byte in the buffer. Therefore, you cannot expect the `read()` to always return 14 bytes, and you cannot expect it to return `-1` with `errno == EINTR` whenever a signal is delivered! Experimenting with this program is very useful, to clarify these in your mind.

I don't remember whether the USB serial drivers in Linux ever produce EPIPE or raise SIGPIPE, but that can definitely occur when using pipes. When using pipes, the most common reason is trying to read after read has already returned zero (end of input). Unless ignored or caught with a signal handler, the process dies much like in a segmentation fault, except that the cause is `SIGPIPE` signal instead of `SIGSEGV`.  With terminal-like character devices, it depends on the driver, I seem to recall.

Finally, I wrote the above code under the weather (flu), so there might be bugs in tharrr. It should be POSIX.1 C99 code, and `gcc -Wall -pedantic` does not complain, but having a stuffed head, I'm not making any promises here. Fixes are more than welcome!

Questions? Comments?

Comment: Hi Nominal. Thanks for your in-depth answer. I clarified a few points in my original post and gave a third example which is very simple yet results in a segmentation fault still.